# uWSGI mules' counterpart in Gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, uwsgi, worker

Does Gunicorn have a separate worker like the uwsgi mules that I can use to offload tasks? I need at least 4 workers dedicated to certain logics. I searched the documentation but I can't find anything that resembles them

I love uwsgi but I found out the hard way that you can bring it down with only one request that has multiple headers(can't limit the size too much bc of my program) so i need to migrate to Gunicorn